# C# sort values from textboxes from min to max

Tags: c#, sorting, textbox, fifo

I want to take the values from my textboxes when I press the FIFO button, detect the smallest one and do the operations starting with the smallest number in `ti` and `t` until the biggest one, then store all that in `tf`.

This is what my program looks like:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
private void fifo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int c = 0;
    //Hace tf

    tfA.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(ta.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(tiA.Text)).ToString();
    c = Convert.ToInt32(tfA.Text);
    tfB.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text) + c).ToString();
    c = Convert.ToInt32(tfB.Text);
    tfC.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tc.Text) + c).ToString();
    c = Convert.ToInt32(tfC.Text);
    tfD.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(td.Text) + c).ToString();
    c = Convert.ToInt32(tfD.Text);
    tfE.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(te.Text) + c).ToString();
    c = Convert.ToInt32(tfE.Text);
    tfF.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tf.Text) + c).ToString();

    // Hace T
    T1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tfA.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(tiA.Text)).ToString();
    T2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tfB.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(tiB.Text)).ToString();
    T3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tfC.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(tiC.Text)).ToString();
    T4.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tfD.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(tiD.Text)).ToString();
    T5.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tfE.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(tiE.Text)).ToString();
    T6.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tfF.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(tiF.Text)).ToString();

    // Hace E
    E1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(T1.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(ta.Text)).ToString();
    E2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(T2.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text)).ToString();
    E3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(T3.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(tc.Text)).ToString();
    E4.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(T4.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(td.Text)).ToString();
    E5.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(T5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(te.Text)).ToString();
    E6.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(T6.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(tf.Text)).ToString();

    //Hace I
    I1.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(ta.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(T1.Text)).ToString();
    I2.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(tb.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(T2.Text)).ToString();
    I3.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(tc.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(T3.Text)).ToString();
    I4.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(td.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(T4.Text)).ToString();
    I5.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(te.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(T5.Text)).ToString();
    I6.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(tf.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(T6.Text)).ToString();

    //X1 2 y 3

    X1.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(T1.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(T2.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(T3.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(T4.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(T5.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(T6.Text)) / 6).ToString();
    X2.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(E1.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(E2.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(E3.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(E4.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(E5.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(E6.Text)) / 6).ToString();
    X3.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(I1.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(I2.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(I3.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(I4.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(I5.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(I6.Text)) / 6).ToString();
    comp1 = Convert.ToDecimal(X3.Text);
}
```

**EDIT: I managed to do what I wanted. I just put the values in an array and sorted them, then equaled the textbox.Text to each one. Worked pretty well. Thank you for the help.**

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by _"detect the smallest one and do the operations starting with the smallest number in ti and t until the biggest one, then store all that in tf."_?

Comment: Sorry, let me elaborate more. I have 18 texboxes in the program (Currently more, but those 18 are the ones that matter). The first column of texboxes is ti, the second is t and the third is tf. Each textbox is named tiA, tiB, tiC, until tiF, the textboxes for t are named ta, tb, tc, td, te, tf. The tf boxes are tfA, tfB, tfC, tfD, tfE, tfF. I want to take the values inserted in tiA until tiF and the values insterted in ta until tf. Determine which value in ti is the smallest one, sort the values smallest to biggest in ti and t and then add those with my variable c and show the result in tf.

Comment: I would place each column of textboxes inside  `Panel`s so you can foreach through the `Panel.Controls` member instead of having to copy that much code.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

```
            // list holding the ti value and the three controls: ti, t and tf
            var controls = new List<Tuple<int, Control, Control, Control>>();

            // add all the controls together with the sorting key, the ti value (just an example, but here you add the tiValue and the ti control, t control and tf control
            controls.Add(new Tuple<int, Control, Control, Control>(0, null, null, null));

            // sort everything
            controls.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.Item1.CompareTo(t2.Item1));

            // loop through the controls in the right order and perform the logic
            foreach (var t in controls)
            {
                var tiValue = t.Item1;
                var tiControl = t.Item2;
                var tControl = t.Item3;
                var tfControl = t.Item4;

                // Do the things to the controls and their values...
            }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I find it difficult to understand. I was thinking of adding all textboxes to an array, perform the operations in the background and then add the results to the tf textboxes.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question then. If you want to process the textboxes in a certain order then you will have to group them in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Can't access pastebin or imgur where I am but I'll give this a shot. Textboxes are a terrible idea for this though.

```
public static void SortAndSumTextboxes()
{
    Form form = new Form();

    var tiControls = form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(tb => Regex.IsMatch(tb.Name, "^ti.$"));
    var tControls = form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(tb => Regex.IsMatch(tb.Name, "^t.$"));

    var tiSorted = tiControls.Select(tb => int.Parse(tb.Text)).OrderBy(i => i);
    var tSorted = tControls.Select(tb => int.Parse(tb.Text)).OrderBy(i => i);

    int c = 1; // some constant
    var tfValues = tiSorted.Zip(tSorted, (a, b) => a + b + c).ToArray();
    var tfControls = form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(tb => tb.Name.StartsWith("tf")).OrderBy(tb => tb.Name).ToArray(); ;

    for (int i = 0; i < tfControls.Length; i++)
    {
        tfControls[i].Text = tfValues[i].ToString();
    }
}
```